# Identifying context in QML file opened in Qt Creator based on user position

Tags: qt, plugins, qt-creator, semantics, qml

Currently I'm developing plugin for Qt Creator which which should give me semantic information
based on user location in QML file opened in text editor (where cursor is set).
For example, if we have the following QML file:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "blue"

    Image {
        source: "pics/logo.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

and user clicks on 'color' plugin should tell that it is inside Rectangle object.

I tried to use the following code:

```
const QmlJS::Snapshot snapshot = modelManager->snapshot();
const QmlJS::Document::Ptr doc = snapshot.document(fileName);
QmlJS::AST::Node *node = doc->ast();
const QmlJS::Interpreter::ObjectValue *scopeObject = doc->bind()->findQmlObject(node);
qDebug() << "QML class" << scopeObject->className();
```

but scopeObject returned is null. ast() and bind() of document are also null, though the document->source shows the correct source file and it is parsed.
The question is how to get the scopeObject or are there any other ways to do this.

Cheers